# I'm trying to put my 2 buttons in my styling divs but I want one of the buttons to be in a form I have and the other outside the submit form

Tags: php, forms, button

I'm trying to put my 2 buttons in my styling divs but I want one of the buttons to be in a form I have and the other outside the submit form so it allows it to load a modal.

Here is my code below

```
<div class="row">
<div class="card-box" style="border-radius: none; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #E3E3E3; background: #EEEEEE;">
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="bulk_delete_submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>

<form name="bulk_action_form" action="" class="form-inline" method="POST"/>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['checked_id'])) {
            $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            foreach($idArr as $id) {
                mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
                echo "<p>".$id ."</p>";
            }
            $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Users have been deleted successfully.';
            header("Location: admin_members.php");
        } else { 
            echo '<div class="row" style="color: red; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> You must select atleast one payment log to delete <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></div>';
        }
    }
?>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the `bulk_delete_submit` button to be placed inside of the form and display inline with the other button outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="card-box" style="border-radius: none; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #E3E3E3; background: #EEEEEE;">

<form name="bulk_action_form" action="" class="form-inline" method="POST"/>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="bulk_delete_submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```